# Armbian_5.24 + orange pi zero + nodejs + gpio access

Tags: node.js, gpio, zero, orange-pi

I successfully installed armbian, WiringOP, I can access gpio.

How can I access gpio from nodejs on orange pi zero?

Here is the gpio output:

```
hygy@orangepizero:~/WiringOP/gpio$ sudo ./gpio readall
[sudo] password for hygy: 
 +-----+-----+----------+------+---+-Orange Pi+---+---+------+---------+-----+--+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name   | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name     | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+----------+------+---+----++----+---+------+----------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |     3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v       |     |     |
 |  12 |   8 |    SDA.0 | ALT5 | 0 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5V       |     |     |
 |  11 |   9 |    SCL.0 | ALT5 | 0 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v       |     |     |
 |   6 |   7 |   GPIO.7 | ALT3 | 0 |  7 || 8  | 0 | ALT3 | TxD3     | 15  | 13  |
 |     |     |       0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 0 | ALT3 | RxD3     | 16  | 14  |
 |   1 |   0 |     RxD2 | ALT5 | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | ALT3 | GPIO.1   | 1   | 110 |
 |   0 |   2 |     TxD2 | ALT5 | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v       |     |     |
 |   3 |   3 |     CTS2 | ALT3 | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | ALT3 | GPIO.4   | 4   | 68  |
 |     |     |     3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | ALT3 | GPIO.5   | 5   | 71  |
 |  64 |  12 |     MOSI | ALT4 | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v       |     |     |
 |  65 |  13 |     MISO | ALT4 | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | ALT3 | RTS2     | 6   | 2   |
 |  66 |  14 |     SCLK | ALT4 | 0 | 23 || 24 | 0 | ALT4 | CE0      | 10  | 67  |
 |     |     |       0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 0 | ALT3 | GPIO.11  | 11  | 21  |
 |  19 |  30 |    SDA.1 | ALT4 | 0 | 27 || 28 | 0 | ALT4 | SCL.1    | 31  | 18  |
 |   7 |  21 |  GPIO.21 | ALT3 | 0 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v       |     |     |
 |   8 |  22 |  GPIO.22 | ALT3 | 0 | 31 || 32 | 0 | ALT3 | RTS1     | 26  | 200 |
 |   9 |  23 |  GPIO.23 | ALT3 | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v       |     |     |
 |  10 |  24 |  GPIO.24 |  OUT | 1 | 35 || 36 | 0 | ALT3 | CTS1     | 27  | 201 |
 |  20 |  25 |  GPIO.25 |  OUT | 1 | 37 || 38 | 0 | ALT5 | TxD1     | 28  | 198 |
 |     |     |       0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | ALT5 | RxD1     | 29  | 199 |
 +-----+-----+----------+------+---+----++----+---+------+----------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name   | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name     | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+----------+------+---+-Orange Pi+---+------+----------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: You could try it with https://github.com/kelly/node-i2c. But please try at least something before asking on here, this is not a tutorial website.

Comment: I tried several things but none of them worked. Ill try this too thanks.

Now I checked this lib, and as I see it is only an i2c lib. I want to access the gpio's like on an espruino or raspberry pi zero.

Comment: basically everythings are files under linux. I assume that nodes.js is able to read/write files, then check http://raspberrypi-aa.github.io/session2/bash.html to learn how to interact with gpio directly. if you only wish to set up down ports, it may work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard streams.

If, for example, you are accessing the GPIO with Python, you can redirect the standard output of that Python process to your Node.js app.

I found this nice tutorial that explains how to do it: http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/